# Get parameters from android to unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-intent, parameters

I have a problem, i want to send a parameter (int) from an app of build in android studio and receive it in an app build it in unity.
The apps work like this, you open the android app, press a botom and open the second app, i send and intent when i open the unity app but idkhow to recieve the param.

I know that are some questions about this but didn't work or maybe idk how to implement it to my code.

This is how i send the param
Java app

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.bodyar");
            if(user!=null){
                launchIntent.putExtra(Constant.TYPE,user.getLearningStyleId());
            }else{
                launchIntent.putExtra(Constant.TYPE,Constant.VISUAL);
            }
            startActivity(launchIntent);
```

but i dont know how to receive the value. I tried the stuff of UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage(), but u just get an error from that

[image]

And the funciton of the Script that it´s attached to GameObjectUI is this

```
 public void TipoTest(string token){
    prueba.text = token;
}
```

And when i export the unity project to android, in the method OnCreate I recieve the params like this

```
public class UnityPlayerActivity extends Activity {

    protected UnityPlayer mUnityPlayer; // don't change the name of this variable; referenced from native code

    // Setup activity layout
    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mUnityPlayer = new UnityPlayer(this);
        setContentView(mUnityPlayer);
        mUnityPlayer.requestFocus();
    }

    @Override protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        // To support deep linking, we need to make sure that the client can get access to
        // the last sent intent. The clients access this through a JNI api that allows them
        // to get the intent set on launch. To update that after launch we have to manually
        // replace the intent with the one caught here.
        setIntent(intent);
    }
}
```

And It works but idk how to pass the variable to unity script

Comment: Can you be more specific about how UnitySendMessage did not work for you?

Comment: Sorry, yes, when i exported the project of unity to android, in the class UnityPlayerActivity.java, in the method OnCreate, there, i receive the param from the other app, the problem is that idk how to conected with c# script. In the method i put UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage("GameObjectUI","TipoTest", String.valueOf(type));

Comment: but i got the error-  Unity: AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: no "Ljava/lang/Object;" field "UnityPlayerActivity" in class "Lcom/unity3d/player/UnityPlayer;" or its superclasses

Comment: Well, since we can't see that code all we can do is guess. In order for that function to work you must have a GameObject named 'GameObjectUI' in your scene, and a script attached to that GameObject with a void function named "TipoTest" that takes one string parameter. We use this all the time, it's not difficult at all.

Comment: Well know i dont get errors just start the app but i doesnt happen nothing, the method i call in UnityPlayer.UnitySendMessage() set text to a Text GameObject with the string that i send but doesnt happen nothing

Comment: Hi, @RetiredNinja, I edited my post with the full info. Maybe will be more clear my problem

Comment: Do you think maybe you should create the UnityPlayer before you try and send messages to it? Doesn't your class just inherit from UnityPlayerActivity? https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/AndroidUnityPlayerActivity.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem is that i don´t have the path "C:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data", i cant find the classes.jar

Comment: Wherever you have Unity installed that's where the file is. Right-click the shortcut you use to open it and select open file location.

Comment: Sorry for this sillies questions but as you can see, i´m new on this. The line that say "Then add classes.jar to the classpath used to compile the new Activity. Compile your Activity source file and package it into a JAR or AAR package, and copy it to your project folder.." what means?